# Spyder dataframe editor format

Tags: python, spyder

Is there a way to set the default format in the Dataframe Editor that comes with spyder?
For example here the default is %.3g, can I leave it as %.6g by default?

[image]

and also is there a command to open this Dataframe editor from whatever code I'm running?

I'm using spyder version 2.3.5.2 that comes with Anaconda Package and windows 7 64bit.

Thanks
Gabriel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) Regarding your questions:

1. There is no way to set the default floating point format. If you feel this is a limitation to your work, please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues), so we don't forget to address it in the future.
2. It's not possible to open our DataFrame editor from a program running outside Spyder. However, we're not opposed to the idea, if someone wants to implement it.

Comment: thanks @Carlos Cordoba. 
1. Will do. 
2. Wasn't clear. I meant opening it from  a code executing with spyder.